# Redirect denied IP addresses using htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have denied some IP addresses using .htaccess.
How to redirect to a page (banned.something.com) when they try to open my website?

**Code:**

```
deny from 176.xx.xxx.xx
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Katie just tell me anything you dont understand with this question ._.

Comment: Hi Smasher535, just giving you some guidance on how to ask a more thorough question so you are more likely to get help.  It is a bit of an open ended question.  Instead, you should try to achieve your goal and then if you run into puzzling errors, come back with those details of what you have tried.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Comment: @Smasher535 don't post code in the comments! You should edit your question to add it.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the banned ip to a specific page or url using the following in htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://banned.example.com
DenyFrom 176.xx.xxx.xx
```